# why does codeigniter's view function just loop once?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my question below when use codeigniter:

1: query id from DB

2: loop to call my function

```
 public function create_all_static_page(){
    $sql = "select id from information where is_static = 0";
    $arr = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
    foreach($arr as $r){
        $this->create_static_temp_page($r['id']);
        echo $r['id'];
    }
}
private  function create_static_temp_page($id){

    //...another code
    $html = $this->load->view('push_db_template_page', $data,true);

    $html = addslashes($html);
    $info['id'] = $id;
    $info['static_content'] = $html;
    if($this->db->replace('static_page',$info)){
        $sql = "update information set is_static = 1 where id = {$id}";
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }

}
```

I have found,it loops just once. That is to say, if I output `$r['id']` after `$this->create_static_temp_page();` just outputs the first id and the foreach loop has been stopped, but I never use 'return' or 'exit' in my code.

Is there anything wrong with `$this->load->view()`?

Comment: how many values are there in your database

Comment: try to echo before calling the create_static_temp_page function  what value u r getting

Comment: just some test data in my database,about 10 rows;

Comment: and this is the array before callling create_static_temp_page :array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '88' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '89' (length=2)

Comment: Is there something breaking your script? Did you enable error reporting?

Comment: no breaking in my code,and i am sure $html = $this->load->view('push_db_template_page', $data,true) stops the loop,if i comments this row,logic is ok, script can echo all $r['id']

Comment: make you `create_static_temp_page` function blank.Now what does your browser outputs?

Comment: And error reporting? There could be something breaking it, maybe `$data`?

Comment: It looks like $data is undefined in your create_static_temp_page() method. Are you trying to pass anything to the view?

Comment: if i make create_static_temp_page blank,browser outputs id number like 88 and 89;my project is production environment,so error_reporting(0);i have defined $data before  $this->load->view(), $data are some variables like $data['name'] = 'name';

Comment: i find some tips on google,it says when after calling $this->load->view(); CodeIgniter's view function will call ob_end_flush();is this the question here?